# When performing an async_write with a tcp socket, when is the handler called?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

This is just a simple question of how async_write behaves with tcp sockets.  Basically, when working with a tcp socket, does the write handler get called when the data gets written to the socket, or when an ack is received from the destination?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, the handler gets called as soon as data are written into the socket's kernel buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Same behavior as the BSD socket's `send()` - it completes when the OS has a copy of the data. This will be before an ACK.

Comment: If that is the case, is there a way I can get a notification when an ACK is received or is this abstracted away from me by this point?

Comment: Yea, that's totally abstracted. I don't think there's even a way to do that without Asio.

Comment: @CraigH I don't think you can do that with Asio. This would require to interact with the tcp/ip stack, and I have no idea how this can be done.

Answer (score 2):

The only guarantee provided by Boost.Asio is that the handler will be called when the operation completes.  In the case of `async_write`, the operation is considered complete when any of the following are true:

- The entire buffer sequence has been written to the stream.
- The operation has been canceled.  For example. `socket_.cancel()`.
- An error occurs.  For example, the remote endpoint closes their socket.

Once the operation completes, the handler is posted for deferred invocation.  However, it is unspecified as to *exactly* when and the order in which handlers will be invoked.  Consider the scenario where an `async_write` operation has been initiated for 2 different sockets.  Any of the following sequences are possible:

1. `async_write` operation 1 completes.
2. operation 1's handler invoked.
3. `async_write` operation 2 completes.
4. operation 2's handler invoked.

1. `async_write` operation 1 completes.
2. `async_write` operation 2 completes.
3. operation 1's handler invoked.
4. operation 2's handler invoked.

1. `async_write` operation 1 completes.
2. `async_write` operation 2 completes.
3. operation 2's handler invoked.
4. operation 1's handler invoked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need high layer protocals. if a remote peer program blows your request package, ACK is also does not fit your need.